# Calculating weekly sales from rolling monthly figures - possible?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am working with colleagues on the following problem, and we've not been able to conclude whether it's solvable or not.  Every week we get a monthly refresh of sales numbers.  We want to calculate what sales were in the most recent week.  Has anyone dealt with this kind of problem before?  Thank you.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? In what format do you get the 'sales numbers' and what are they?

Comment: What do you mean "every week we get a monthly refresh"?  Do you mean that each week you get the total sales over the past four weeks? If so then you can "bootstrap" the calculation...that is, if you knew the weekly sales over the prior weeks $\{w_i\}$ then $w_n=m_n - m_{n-1} +w_{n-4}$.  If you don't know any of the weekly history then the monthly sales don't determine the weekly ones.

Comment: Thank you for your questions.  Every week we get an update of certain product sales via a distributor.  For whatever reasons, they cannot break into weeks (I'm in China, FYI).  Putting aside the obvious question of why they can't do it, we've just been trying to do the work ourselves with what we have.  @ lulu, unfortunately we do not have any of the historical weeks.  Do you mean by your last sentence that you do not think this is solvable?  Thank you.

Comment: @Brian.  Yes.  If you have none of the weekly history then it is not solvable.  In my posted "solution" I show two weekly histories that give rise to the same monthly history.

Answer (score 0):

Let us denote by $w_i$ the weekly sales in week $i$.  Then, the way I read the question, you are given $m_i=w_i+w_{i-1}+w_{i-2}+w_{i-3}$ and you would like to recover the $w_i$ from this.

As stated, that is not possible.  For example suppose that the weekly sales were a constant $3$.  Then, every monthly sales figure would be $12$.  On the other hand, if the weekly sales figures followed the pattern $\{4,4,4,0,4,4,4,0,4,4,4,0,\cdots\}$ then you'd also get $12$ for every monthly sales figure.

If, however, you know the prior weeks' history then you can do it.  Indeed for all $n$ we have $$w_n=m_n - m_{n-1}+w_{n-4}$$  (which you can see by simply writing out the definitions of $m_n$ and $m_{n-1}$).

Comment: I see, thank you very much for taking the time to explain your thoughts, very useful.

Comment: In practice, you can sometimes approach questions like this by declaring something about the weekly figures.  Maybe you know they are roughly constant, maybe you know they are highly seasonal, something like that.  If you can describe the weekly sales with a few open parameters then you can fit those parameters to the monthly data.  To be sure, none of this is possible unless you know something about the weekly data.